# Can I program an amazon IOT button to perform a keystroke for an open application?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I want to be able to toggle the mute setting for Zoom video conferencing meetings. Is there a way that I can execute the keystroke shortcode by programming an amazon IOT button? I have limited developing experience but figured it might be a simple place to start.

I have done some digging and my friend suggests I just assign a keystroke macro to an xbox controller instead.

Comment: How can the video conferencing system "receive" the mute request? Is it running on a computer, or a wall panel? Is there an API to receive requests from an external system?

Answer (score 0):

An Amazon IoT button will send a message to the Amazon IoT service.

You would need some software sitting on the computer (or control panel?) that either regularly checks the status of the button in IoT, or can receive an API request from a Lambda function that is triggered by IoT.

**Bottom line:** Probably not a good use-case for an IoT button.